# not sure why my CNN model isn't getting past 0.03 acc

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using a CNN model to classify the spectrograms of different audio files.
this is the model, I created

```
input_shape = (128, 216, 1)
def create_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), strides = (1,1), name = 'conv0', input_shape = input_shape))
    
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn0'))
    model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides = (1,1), name='conv1'))
    model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D((3, 3), name='avg_pool'))
    
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(300, activation='relu', name='rl'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='softmax', name='sm'))

    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics='acc')
    return model
```

I'm using this to get the spectrograms from a file

```
for filename in pbar(os.listdir(save_file + r"spec-samples/")):
    image_raw = tf.io.read_file(save_file + r"spec-samples/" + filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
    X.append(image)
```

and this to get the labels from a csv file

```
def reload_labels():
    y = []
    for data in tqdm(df.iterrows(), desc='Progress'):
        y.append(data[1][1])
    return y
```

when I fit the model via

```
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    checkpoint, monitor='accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

es_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='loss', patience=3, verbose=1)

csv_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(save_file + "logs.csv", separator=',', append=False)

history = model.fit(
    X_, y_,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[cp_callback, es_callback, csv_callback])
```

the highest accuracy I get is 0.026 which is obviously not great

this is an example of one of the spectrograms
[spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMbdq.png)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: One possibility is that the problem you're feeding it is too hard. There are two ways to gauge that: 1) Has this problem been solved elsewhere with better than 0.026 accuracy? 2) If you wrote a program that gave random answers, how high would the accuracy be? If your program does worse than that, that's a strong sign there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: The output layer, being 50 neurons with sigmoid, is one problem. Try with `softmax`. Your loss also needs to be `sparsecategoricalcrossentropy`. `binarycrossentropy` is for binary classification. With 50 neurons, you need more. If you're classifying two classes, keep what you have and change the neuron number to 1. Is it training accuracy or testing accuracy that's 0.026? With 50 neurons, 0.026 is roughly the same as 1/50, or in your case, randomly guessing.

Comment: Are you sure that labels and examples do correspond each other? `os.listdir` function does not guarantee any order, so you may be using wrong labels.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by your code. If I understand it you are feeding the network with images of spectrograms and I assume binary labels. The top layer of your model is

```
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', name='sm')
```

where does the value 50 come from? I would expect the last layer to have 1 node.
Also are you sure you have maintained the order of the images X to line up with the labels Y since they are coming from 2 different sources.

If you have 50 categories (classes) then the top layer should use activation softmax

Comment: there are 50 different categories of the images and I did check, the images do line up with the labels

Comment: then the activation function for the last layer should be  softmax